Wpf TextBox Style
I have a problem. I created a TextBox in c# wpf. And I gave a style to the textbox. The codes are like this ;
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="txtBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6 3"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdane"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="Transparent" Focusable="True" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="5" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Cursor="IBeam"/>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Blue"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Blue"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="txt_1"  Height="100" Width="100" Style="{DynamicResource txtBoxStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" Panel.ZIndex="5" />
            <Button x:Name="btn_Tikla" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Blue" Click="btn_Tikla_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

When I run the application and want to enter data, text is written but it does not appear.
I can create a button and see in the messagebox object whether the text has been written or not.
As far as I understand, I need to create an interaction between the border I created and the textbox.I tried combinations such as text color and background color, but I did not get any results. I would be very happy if anyone can help.Giving my own style in textbox.

When you create a custom style for a TextBox, you need to ensure it includes a component to display text. Your current design has a border but lacks a content area for the text. To fix this, add a ScrollViewer inside the Border in your ControlTemplate. This ScrollViewer will act as the text area.
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="Transparent" Focusable="True" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="5" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Cursor="IBeam">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>


It's in your code but you might want to highlight the fact that it has to be named PART_ContentHost. This is actually the most important criteria so the control knows where to paint the text editor element.

thanks your answer.☺️ I've tried this before, but I didn't change the name to PART_ContentHost.

@YETİ When creating custom templates for element, pay attention to the TemplatePartAttribute attributes in element classes. This attributies specifies the required template elements - their type and name. Such attributes are specified when the behavior of an element has direct dependencies on the presence of these parts of the template. And their absence, accordingly, will affect the behavior of the element.
